# Filtering data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Below you can see my data frame.

```
df<-data.frame( 
                items=c("1 Food Item 1",
                "1.1 Food Item 2",
                "01.1.1 Food Item 3",
                "01.1.2 Food Item 4",
                "01.1.3 Food Item 5",
                "2 Food Item 6",
                "2.1 Food Item 7",
                "02.1.1 Food Item 8",
                "10 Food Item 9",
                "10.1 Food Item 10",
                "10.1.1 Food Item 11",
                "10.1.2 Food Item 12")
    )

df
```

This `df` contains items that begin with different numbers with **two**, **three**, and **four** digits. Now I want to filter this `df`, and the final output should be items only with **four digits**:

```
"01.1.1 Food Item 3",
"01.1.2 Food Item 4",
"01.1.3 Food Item 5",
"02.1.1 Food Item 8",
"10.1.1 Food Item 11",
"10.1.2 Food Item 12"
```

So can anybody help me with how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subset` with `grepl` in `base R` - matches the pattern of 2 digits (`\\d{2}`) followed by a dot, then a digit, followed by a dot and another digit and spaces (`\\s+`) after

```
subset(df, grepl("^\\d{2}\\.\\d\\.\\d\\s+", items))
```

-output

```
           items
3   01.1.1 Food Item 3
4   01.1.2 Food Item 4
5   01.1.3 Food Item 5
8   02.1.1 Food Item 8
11 10.1.1 Food Item 11
12 10.1.2 Food Item 12
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(stringr)
df<-data.frame( 
  items=c("1 Food Item 1",
          "1.1 Food Item 2",
          "01.1.1 Food Item 3",
          "01.1.2 Food Item 4",
          "01.1.3 Food Item 5",
          "2 Food Item 6",
          "2.1 Food Item 7",
          "02.1.1 Food Item 8",
          "10 Food Item 9",
          "10.1 Food Item 10",
          "10.1.1 Food Item 11",
          "10.1.2 Food Item 12")
)

idx <- df$items |> str_detect('^\\d{2}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}') |> which()
df[ idx, ] |> print()
```